# How to list pages in Ghost CMS?

Tags: ghost-blog

I'm trying to show pages on my homepage.

In my **home.hbs** I have

```
{{!-- The tag above means: insert everything in this file
into the {body} of the default.hbs template --}}

{{#is "home"}}
    {{#if @site.description}}
    <header class="page-head">
        <h2 class="page-head-title">{{@site.description}}</h2>
    </header>
    {{/if}}
{{/is}}

{{#get "posts" filter="page:true"}}
  {{#foreach posts}}
    {{title}}
    <p>{{excerpt words="33"}}</p>
  {{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
```

Nothing is listed on my homepage. This works for posts but not pages for some reason.

I have the article featured, and it has "Category" tag - is it possible to display these on the homepage?

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there, try this:

```
{{#is "home"}}
    {{#if @site.description}}
    <header class="page-head">
        <h2 class="page-head-title">{{@site.description}}</h2>
    </header>
    {{/if}}
{{/is}}

{{#get "pages" limit="all"}}
  {{#foreach pages}}
    {{title}}
    <p>{{excerpt words="33"}}</p>
  {{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
```

Hope this helps :)